# Is an excel Worksheet type a value type or reference type?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to know if passing a `Worksheet` ByValue would copy the content of the worksheet.

Is an excel `Worksheet` type a value type or reference type?

Thanks.

Comment: no .. only the basic VBA types are value type https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177324.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Reference type.  http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/byrefbyval.aspx